# Detener el auto en el tiempo exacto y distancia recorrida (MRUV)

Tags: java, java-swing, animación

Estoy haciendo una calculadora MRUV y a la vez quiero agregar la animación de un Auto, pero sucede que tengo problemas en detener el auto en el tiempo calculado según las fórmulas del MRUV.

**clase Car**

```
public class Car {

    private final ImageIcon imagen;
    private double posx;
    private int width;

    public Car() {
        imagen = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/carred.png"));
        posx = 10;
        width = 400;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g){
        g.drawImage(imagen.getImage(), (int) posx , 50, width, 300, null);
    }

    public void move(double x){
        posx+=x;
    }

     // getters y setters
}
```

**JPanel**

```
private void btnCalcActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

    String text_vf = txfvf.getText();
    String text_v0 = txfv0.getText();
    String text_a = txfa.getText();
    String text_d = txfd.getText();
    String text_t = txft.getText();
    String res = "message.. res";

    // Calculos....        

    //aqui paso el tiempo, aceleracion, v0(veloc. inicial) y distancia calculados
    moveCarImage(t, Integer.parseInt(text_v0), a, Integer.parseInt(text_d));
}           


private void moveCarImage(double tiempo, double v0, double aceleracion, int distancia) {
    timer = new Timer(tiempo, (e) -> {
        car.move(aceleracion);
        repaint();

        if (car.getPosx() >= distancia+car.getWidth() ) {
            System.out.println("Carro detenido..");
            timer.stop();
        }
    });

    timer.start();
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    car.draw(g);
}
```

También busco que el carro no sobrepase el ancho del JFrame .. He intentado muchas cosas y no me sale, además que si paso los segundos calculados al `Timer` , el auto irá muy rápido y pues, acabará antes del tiempo calculado, ya que son milisegundos. Y si lo multiplico * 1000 , irá muy retrasado.

Comment: Para empezar en ningún momento cambias la velocidad... ni siquiera usas el valor para nada. Antes de empezar a escribir el programa deberías entender cuál ha de ser su comportamiento, y lo que significa cada valor.

Comment: Con el método move(aceleracion).. el auto si se mueve. La v0 no me sirve en el método que hace la animación, lo puse por error.

Comment: Se mueve, pero no como MRUV. Lo dicho, necesitas entender qué es lo que tiene que hacer el programa; sino es imposible que salga. Es como ponerse a conducir sin tener ni idea a dónde se supone que tienes que ir.

Comment: Pero se supone que la aceleración, es lo que recorre por cada segundo según el MRUV. La aceleración es constante. Si la aceleración es 5 m/s . Y empieza en 10, luego 15, 20, etc. En todo caso podría ayudarme por favor.